# SSRS Color Gradient

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been able to figure out how to make certain values the certain colors I would like. However, I'd really like to be able to create a color gradient so that it's more of a gradual change between each value.

0 = white

from white to green between 1 and 15,

gradient from  green to yellow between 16 and 25,

and gradient from yellow to red between 26 and 35,

anything above 35 is red.

This is the code I have in the background fill expression:

```
=SWITCH(
(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) = 0, "White",
((Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) >= 1 and 
(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) <= 15), "Green", 
((Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) >= 16 and 
(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) <= 25), "Yellow", 
((Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) >= 26 and 
(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value))) <= 35, "Orange", 
(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)) > 35, "Red")
```

[This is the matrix I have so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7uVn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this answer I wrote a while back. It's for a chart but the principle should be the same.

the basic idea is to calculate the colour in SQL and then use that to set the color properties in SSRS

[Applying Custom Gradient to Chart Based on Count of Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59796100/applying-custom-gradient-to-chart-based-on-count-of-value/59824503#59824503)

---

**Keeping it all in SSRS**

---

If you want to keep this within the report you could write a function to do the calculation.

For a very simple red gradient, it might look something like this..

```
Public Function CalcRGB (minVal as double, maxVal as double, actualVal as double) as String

Dim RedValue as integer
Dim GreenValue as integer
Dim BlueValue as integer

RedValue = ((actualVal - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)) * 256
GreenValue = 0
BlueValue = 0

dim result as string

result = "#" & RedValue.ToString("X2") & greenValue.ToString("X2") & BlueValue.ToString("X2")

Return result

End Function
```

In this function I have set green and blue to 0 but these could be calculated too based on requirements.

To use this function as a background colour, set the Background Color property to something like

```
=Code.CalcRGB(
              MIN(Fields!myColumn.Value),
              MAX(Fields!myColumn.Value),
              Fields!myColumn.Value
              )
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it without altering the SQL code?

Comment: I have entered the function into the report code just as you wrote it, and set my background color to `=Code.CalcRGB(
              MIN(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)),
              MAX(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)),
              Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value)
              )` and nothing is happening to the color... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you tried to do is correct but obviously if the results of the expression you are passing as parameters to the function are wrong then that will need to be fixed. I would suggest you add 3 additional columns and set each to be the same as the expression you are using in the CalcRGB call. e.g. the first column expression would be  `MIN(Sum(Fields!Total_Transaction_Count.Value) / CountDistinct(Fields!TransUserNumber.Value))` . Make sure you get the numbers you are expecting and go from there. I did test this and it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help. I got it working, but I'm not sure how to manipulate the colors from white, green, yellow, orange to red. I have it where it gets from a lighter to very dark green.

Comment: Its just a case of working out what values you need for each component of red green and blue and calculating them in the function, at the moment only red is changing. It can be pain to get an expression that calculates then properly but with a bit of trial and error and a bit of logic applied you'll get there. If you get stuck post another question specifically about this issue with exact requirements and I'm sure somebody on SO will be able to help. Good luck